# Is it possible to :noexport: a single figure?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

In org-mode, is there a way to use `:noexport:` on a single item such as a figure, so that it is displayed in Emacs but not in exported files (such as docx)?

Below is an example code of a figure I'd like to hide during exports:

```
#+ATTR_ORG: :width 200
#+CAPTION: an example figure.
#+LABEL: fig-mine
[[file:./fig-mine.png]]
```

I understand that `:noexport` can be used to hide an entire section in an org file. But I need more fine-grained control to hide just one image from exports. I thought about putting the image in a section. But since sections have no ending marks, hiding the image section with `:noexport:` would hide everything after it until the end of the parent section.

*Is there a way to use :noexport: on a single item without affecting other texts?*

(as of org-mode 9.4.6 in Emacs 27)

Comment: You can wrap it in `#+BEGIN_EXPORT foo ... #+END_EXPORT`: it will only be included if there is such an export engine and you are exporting to it.

Comment: Not being able to end a section is the main trouble.